# How to reference for example a ng-template with the hash #content

Tags: angular

Below my code:

`modal-checkout.component.html`

```
  <ng-template #content let-modal>
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
         ...
```

`modal-checkout.component.ts`

```
@ViewChild('content') contentRef: TemplateRef<> ??????
```

Question: How can I reference the #content in modal-checkout.component.ts?

Answer (score 0):

You call it with whatever follows the ViewChild():

```
@ViewChild('content') contentRef;

// call in a function or onInit()
testFunction() {

  // The call looks like this
  this.contentRef.DO_SOMETHING_HERE

  // Log out content to see what it looks like
  console.log('content', this.contentRef);
}
```